# I need an API that gets "input data"field from the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, message, api

See image for the field I'm trying to get the data from, I can decode it myself, but I can't download the entire blockchain so how do I access the "input data" field? Would an API be the way to go?
[image: Input Data]

I've tried BSCscan, but it doesn't give this field, sadly, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Any other APIs that definitely have "input data"? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Binance's api for this purpose. Go there:
https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/beaconchain/develop/api-reference/node-rpc/

Scroll to `6. APIs` and then look at `6.1 query APIs`.

Comment: thanks you :) I got something working in the mean time, but this could help others too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few more things and this code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

web3.eth.getTransaction('0x5abc50f76ded7659c135029ed37f603728731ec69007dbb7a75adb615a1bd6d8').then(console.log)
```

returns a bunch of data including

```
  input: '0x6d61696e206e65742121',
```

which is the hex of the message